# EF6 doesn't create any tables with code first

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mysql-connector

Requisites: ASP MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6 and MySQL.

So in visual studio 2013 i have created a new asp mvc 5 project and, with NuGet, installed the following packets:

- EntityFramework (6.1.3)
- MySql.Data (6.9.8)
- MySql.Data.Entity (6.9.8)
- MySql.Web (6.9.8)

I have followed this tutorial [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) :i have created the model, the context, the seed ecc... and setup the connection string to:

```
<add name="SchoolContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=passwtest;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=dbtest"/>
```

Now when i try to access the Students index page i have the following exception:

```
{"Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations."}
```

I see the database and the entity framework doesn't have created any tables in the dbtest schema. Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is almost always due to using the wrong initializer. Replace DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges with something else like DropCreateDatabaseAlways or CreateDatabaseIfNotExists. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx